# Pass my just created VM's IP as an extension's parameter of the same VM

Tags: json, azure

I created an ARM template which deploys a virtual machine called 'VM1' and then an extension for that virtual machine; that extension calls a PowerShell script on some repo, and I am passing some parameters to it successfully.

My question is: how do I pass the IP of the virtual machine 'VM1' as a parameter of this extension correctly within the same template?

```
{
          "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
          "apiVersion": "2019-12-01",
          "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachines_VM_name'),'/', 'Mypowershell')]",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
         "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachines_VM_name'))]"
        ],
          "properties": {
              "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
              "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
              "typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
              "autoUpgradeMinorVersion":true,
              "settings": {
                "fileUris": [
                  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/********/********/master/powershell.ps1"
                ],
                "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File powershell.ps1', ' -database ', parameters('DataBaseName'), 
                ' -uid ', parameters('adminUsername'), ' -pwd ', parameters('adminPassword'), ' -dbserver ', parameters('servers_dbserver_name'), ' -vmip ', parameters('VM_IP'))]"
              }
          }}
```

Just for the record, in the code above I tried to pass the VM's IP as an ARM parameter but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my powershell file is in my repo but runs within the VM, that is what an extension does, so i was able to put the following line in my powershwll file:

```
$publicIp = (Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json).ip
```

So i did not have to pass this as a parameter in my ARM template in order to use it in my powershell.